# issue while running 'superset db upgrade', cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security'

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to install Apache superset and while runing superset db upgrade i am getting the error 'cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security', can you please help?

> python -V

```
Python 3.8.13
```

> pip freeze

```
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
alembic==1.9.4
amqp==5.1.1
apache-superset==2.0.1
apispec==3.3.2
async-generator==1.10
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==22.2.0
Babel==2.11.0
backoff==2.2.1
bcrypt==4.0.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
bleach==3.3.1
Brotli==1.0.9
cachelib==0.4.1
celery==5.2.7
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
click==8.1.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.6
convertdate==2.4.0
cron-descriptor==1.2.35
croniter==1.3.8
cryptography==38.0.4
defusedxml==0.7.1
deprecation==2.1.0
dnspython==2.3.0
email-validator==1.3.1
exceptiongroup==1.1.0
Flask==2.2.3
Flask-AppBuilder==4.2.1
Flask-Babel==2.0.0
Flask-Bcrypt==1.0.1
Flask-Caching==1.11.1
Flask-Compress==1.13
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.4.4
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-Migrate==4.0.4
Flask-OpenID==1.3.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
flask-talisman==1.0.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
frozenlist==1.3.3
func-timeout==4.3.5
geographiclib==2.0
geopy==2.3.0
graphlib-backport==1.0.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
h11==0.14.0
hashids==1.3.1
hijri-converter==2.2.4
holidays==0.14.2
humanize==4.6.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
importlib-resources==5.12.0
isodate==0.6.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.0.3
jsonschema==4.17.3
kombu==5.2.4
korean-lunar-calendar==0.3.1
Mako==1.2.4
Markdown==3.4.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
marshmallow==3.19.0
marshmallow-enum==1.5.1
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.26.1
msgpack==1.0.4
multidict==6.0.4
numpy==1.22.1
outcome==1.2.0
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.3.5
parsedatetime==2.6
pgsanity==0.2.9
pkgutil_resolve_name==1.3.10
polyline==2.0.0
prison==0.2.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.36
pyarrow==5.0.0
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.6.0
PyMeeus==0.5.12
pyOpenSSL==22.1.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.19.3
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.21.1
python-geohash==0.8.5
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2022.7.1
PyYAML==6.0
redis==4.5.1
selenium==4.8.2
simplejson==3.18.3
six==1.16.0
slackclient==2.5.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.24
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.37.9
sqloxide==0.1.15
sqlparse==0.3.0
superset==0.30.1
tabulate==0.8.9
trio==0.22.0
trio-websocket==0.9.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
urllib3==1.26.14
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.6
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.2.3
wsproto==1.2.0
WTForms==2.3.3
WTForms-JSON==0.3.5
yarl==1.8.2
zipp==3.14.0
```

"ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.flask 2.2.3 requires Werkzeug>=2.2.2, but you have werkzeug 2.0.3 which is incompatible."

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
pip install flask==2.2.3
pip install Werkzeug==2.3.1
```

In superset_config.py I replaced import from werkzeug libraries to others